# Promises not running in the expected order

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, I have a bunch of promises that need to run in order.
In this example, function 4 runs before function 3 has completed.
All functions called here return a promise.

```
await self.function1()
  .then(await function () {
    self.function2()
  })
  .then(await function () {
    return self.function3()
  })
  .then(await function () {
    return self.function4()
  })
```

Comment: Understand what you are doing. You should be using one of `async-await` or `Promise.then`

Comment: You are missing the `return` in front of  `self.function2()`, and you should definitely never `await` a function expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this, You should be using one of `async-await` or `Promise.then`

```
async function test() {
    await self.function1();
    await self.function2();
    const response1 = await self.function3();
    const response2 = await self.function4(response1);
    return response2;
}
```

OR

```
function test() {
    return self.function1()
        .then(() => self.function2())
        .then(() => self.function3())
        .then((response1) => self.function4(response1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this was really helpful. I found out eventually, because the functions I was calling contained promises without async specified, this article helped me understand also. 
https://blog.adriaan.io/make-async-await-work-in-promises.html